# airflow pool value from xcom at runtime

Tags: airflow

There are three pools `low`, `medium` and `high` and are configured with a slot of 1, 2 and 3.

Now, `task1` set xcom value of `pool` based on some calculation and `task2` needs be scheduled in that pool.

Sample code -

```
dag = DAG("mongo-connection-test")

def test(**kwargs):
    # some condition to set pool value
    pool = "high" 
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key="pool", value=pool)

task1 = PythonOperator(task_id="set_xcom",
                       python_callable=test,
                       xcom_push=True, 
                       provide_context=True,
                       dag=dag)

task2 = BashOperator(
                   task_id="test",
                   bash_command="echo Hello !!",
                   dag=dag,
                   pool='{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="set_xcom", key="pool") }}',
                   provide_context=True)
task1 >> task2
```

But task2 is unable to pull value from xcom and scheduler will fail to execute saying no pool`exist '{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="test", key="pool") }}'`. 
Need help in fixing this?

Comment: `pool` is not part of `template_fields` which means jinja template won't be translated. You might need to restructure tasks.  On a side note, when you `xcom_pull`, you set task ID to the one pushing whose tasks you are pulling the xcom from (`set_xcom`).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read the documentation about [Jinja Templating in Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#jinja-templating).
If you want to use it, try to look at the `template_fields` in the source code first (e.g. [BashOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/bash.py#L65))

Since `pool` is not in that list, what you are trying to do won't work.

Therefore, I would recommend you to create your task 3 times with the 3 different pool settings and use a `BranchPythonOperator` to select which of the 3 tasks should run (you can pull from XCom in the `BranchPythonOperator`)

Your DAG should probably look like this:

```
task1 >> branch_task >> [task2_low, task2_medium, task2_high]
```

Comment: This does not seem scalable